# Cypress Form Submit Download file issue test failed

Tags: form-submit, cypress

Cypress test case failed on button click.Please give me proper solution.

Comment: Be descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check first if this button visible or not so

```
cy.get('button').should('be.visible')
```

if this action passed you can do click

```
cy.get('button').click();
```

and if you give us more details (error message, selector, screenshot ... ) would be awesome